# SonataAdmin change template list for Admin Users

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-2.3

i am a new user in sonata admin + fosuserbunle. I need create a new template for list when user is a admin. Check and redirect in CRUD controller or in the sonata admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need admin class and change the style template, the best option is redirect in de sonata admin class. Overwrite getTemplate() method.

```
class YourEntityAdmin extends Admin {

     public function getTemplate($name)
     {
         if ($this->configurationPool->getContainer()->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) 
         {
            switch ($name) {
                case 'list':
                    return 'YourBundle:Entity:list.html.twig';
                default:
                    return parent::getTemplate($name);
            }
        } else {
            return parent::getTemplate($name);
        }
    }
```